# Xcode missed "Push to Remote"

Tags: xcode, version-control

First project that I am trying to enforce committing to a BitBucket repo. Following an online tutorial (which is NOT using source control) and I accidentally missed to check the "Push to Remote" option.

Now my project, under Branches, is showing "1 commit ahead".

How do I get things back in sync? Do I need to revert to the previous commit, and redo the last code changes? Or can I just force another merge?

Comment: Xcode > Source Control > Push?..

Comment: @mag_zbc Thanks. I actually just did that. And something messed up happened. My branch's name was `automation/pushToHOc` and I had already made 40 commits and pushed to my remote branch using the command line. Then when I used your suggestion, Xcode was prompting me to **create `origin/automation/pushTohOc`** it just by itself changed `H` to `h`. It's very weird.

Answer (score 2):

This means you have one commit yet to be pushed so you're ahead of the remote branch. Just push the repository: **Source Control** -> **Push...** -> **Select the branch you want to push**

[image: Push image]

Comment: thanks. when I try this, it only shows "Loading" in the dropdown field. Clicking Push does not seem to do anything.

Comment: @jingo_man check the updated response, it should show you something like this

Comment: thanks again. I wonder if Xcode is "disconnected"? As mine does not display any branches, it just says "Loading...". I have tried restarting Xcode and the laptop

Comment: @jingo_man Do you mean you don't have connection to the internet? If this does not work try it with the terminal: Open terminal -> cd to project folder -> git push origin [branch_name]